# relational database content search role permissions

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, relational-database

I know that this question may sound quite general, but I want to opt for an advice.

I have a relational db model (Postgresql) like the following.

http://www.ebl.bg/model.png

Where all users belong to Roles. I also have Objects with searchable content (text or tsvector - it does not affect the speed of a search query) and each object has Versions.
Users are only allowed to see certain VERSIONS of Objects based on the Roles they are in and the specific permissions for reading and writing this role is given for a specific objects.

Now my question is, is there any Full Text search implementation that also works with Permissions based on user roles (although I really don't see how that would work) or any hint how to cache results for users, having in mind that the results are constantly changing (e.g content is created or deleted)

Currently the search is done by normal JOIN postgresql queries, which is quite slow. Full text indexes does not help.

Comment: Please show a typical query and state how long it takes to execute.

Comment: I cannot post here the typical query - the database is much more complicated than I described here with additional tables, subroutines, etc. We have tried optimisation but they does not really help. What I am asking actually is are there any "best practices" for implementation of such cases where the content search is combined with complex permissions system because I event don't know where to begin the search with.
I am not looking for a specific answer, but just for a hint :)